# Speed up audio while keeping pitch untouched in python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, wav

I was wondering how to speed up audio and maintain its pitch in python. I know how to read, speed up, and save the audio file. The problem is that I do not know how to keep the original audio's pitch untouched. I'm currently using wave to speed up the audio. The code I'm using comes from a similar question but doesn't implement keeping the original pitch. The code is below:

import wave

```
CHANNELS = 1
swidth = 2
Change_RATE = 2

spf = wave.open('VOZ.wav', 'rb')
RATE=spf.getframerate()
signal = spf.readframes(-1)

wf = wave.open('changed.wav', 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(swidth)
wf.setframerate(RATE*Change_RATE)
wf.writeframes(signal)
wf.close()
```

Comment: You are going to have to use something that has `pitch control`. In my experience (linux) both `vlc` and `gstreamer1.0` provide methods for `pitch control` and both have `python` interfaces

Comment: I'll take a look. I didn't know they had interfaces. Thank you!

Comment: What you are looking for is "time stretching".

Comment: This is, like Danijel said, time stretching. Note that the algorithms for this are very complicated, and most of the very good ones are proprietary, so don't get your hopes for the results up too much.

Comment: @user562 here are the algorithms Techniques [link](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31850/slow-down-music-playing-while-maintaining-frequency/31861#31861)